# wordpress links showing absolute path instead of relative path

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed a wordpress site, i have lot of links pointing to various other pages of same site.but each link is pointing to the absolute path of the page.

for Ex:

Link to about page should be

```
  About  ->   www.ecwpamp.com/about
```

but right now it is

```
About  ->   http://aqesafs.netsolhost.com/ecwpampsit22/about
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: There is a discussion somewhere on wordpress, where they explain, why they use only absolute links and no relative. Maybe there is a plugin somewhere to circumvent this ...

Comment: can you elaborate what is ecwpampsit22 in your URL ?

Comment: @laraib its a directory where i uploaded wp files.

Comment: [This method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) might help you.